# PHP preg_split remove commas and trailing white-space

Tags: php, preg-split

The code below has been taken directly from [PHP: preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) - Manual

Example #1 preg_split() example : Get the parts of a search string

```php
<?php
// split the phrase by any number of commas or space characters,
// which include " ", \r, \t, \n and \f
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", "hypertext language, programming");
print_r($keywords);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => hypertext
    [1] => language
    [2] => programming
)
```

I am creating a tagging system which will allow people to type anything into a text box and upon return the text will be processed and inserted into the database. The data could be one word or a phrase, if more than one tag is typed, it will be split using a comma.

**Therefore I would like to be able to keep "hypertext language" as is, so only strip the white-space at the beginning and end of the string and also any white-space after a comma, but not between words which may be phrases.**

Comment: Try using explode with ", " as the delimiter.
See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: I have tried that, however, not always a comma, I was updating the question as you commented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/array_map), [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) and [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/trim):

```
<?php
    $keywords = array_map('trim', explode(',', 'hypertext language, programming'));
    print_r($keywords);
?>
```

Which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hypertext language
    [1] => programming
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/n0GQgj2R)

Comment: Nice and succinct. Would also suggest strtolower to keep tags case insensitive.

Comment: What is the preferred method, preg_split or your method?

Comment: @Mike Stay away from regex if you're doing something as simple as this. Rule of thumb is that regex should only be used if the "regular" solution is horribly complicated or impossible (neither of which is the case here).

Comment: Is there any particular reason why?

Comment: @Mike Regex is much slower? Pure performance. `\s*,+\s*` needs to go through "there can be space here. Is there a space here? Yes. Is there a space next? Yes. Is there a space after that? Is there space after that? No. Okay - then we need to have at least one comma. Is the next character a comma? No? Oh" all the time. Regex does a bunch of backtracing which makes it much slower and a simple `explode` does.

Comment: @Mike Check out [this](http://regex101.com/r/uM0bA6/#debugger) to see the "steps". Compare that to the one step `explode` takes.

Answer (score 9):

**I think it'is the best choice.**

```
$keywords = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', "hypertext language, programming", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**First of all** "Regex is much slower" is wrong, because it's always depends on the pattern. In this case preg_split() is faster.

**Second** preg_split is more readable and as practice shows more profitable option. Keep it simple.

```
$b = "hypertext language, programming";

$time = microtime(1);
for ($i=1; $i<100000; $i++)
    $a = array_map('trim', explode(',', $b)); // Split by comma
printf("array_map(trim), explode  = %.2f\n", microtime(1)-$time);

$time = microtime(1);
for ($i=1; $i<100000; $i++)
    $a = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $b);     // Split by comma
printf("Preg split = %.2f\n", microtime(1)-$time);
```

---

```
array_map(trim), explode  = 0.32
Preg split = 0.22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$to= xyz@ab.com,aaa@abc.com,bbb@abd.com,cc@abe.com;

$toArr = preg_split('[\,]', $to);
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation along with your code as that will improve your answer.