# Remove commas from php array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I'm currently working on displaying some arrays using PHP and MySQL.

Simplified code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM workorder";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc3,$sql);
$tryout_reports = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
   $tryout_reports[] = $row['file_name'] . "<br />";
}
$detail_report['tryout_reports'] = $tryout_reports;
```

I took a lot out of the SQL here, so if there's something wrong in there please don't mind. The SQL statement works fine.

The problem is it's being outputted with commas separating each value, and it's looking real bad.

The HTML on the page when run looks something like this:

```
File1.pdf <br>
","
File2.pdf <br>
","
etc..
```

Now, I've looked around quite a bit and i've tried the following:

```
ltrim()
rtrim()
explode()
str_replace()
```

I know rtrim works, but it doesn't remove the commas. I tried something like:

```
$tryout_reports[] = rtrim($row['file_name'],"pdf");
```

And it took the pdf out of the end of each one, but when I replace "pdf" with "," it does nothing.

Feeling really stuck, any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT: Forgot to add, the page that uses this data and displays it on the page has this:

```
table.append("<tr><th>Tryout Reports </th><td>" + data[0].tryout_reports + "</td></tr>");
```

That is inside of a jQuery function which runs when a job number is clicked to display additional information.

Comment: So where's the code which outputs values?

Comment: It's on a separate page. Using TWIG framework. There isn't much there, very basic. I'll edit it into the question, though

Comment: That comma comes from javascript because you parse directly the array. You can use join: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_split remove commas and trailing white-space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572738/php-preg-split-remove-commas-and-trailing-white-space)

Comment: where is comma added ?. As per your code, I don't see the comma..

Comment: @Stefan Thank you very much! Fixed the problem exactly like I wanted. If you want to make that an answer I'll accept it for you. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Bijan it's not, I've tried that one and it did not solve the problem

Comment: @Asik if you look in the HTML code I posted the comma is in double quotes underneath each line

Comment: ok got it and Stefan explained above..thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comma comes from javascript because you parse directly the array. You can use join: w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp